# Do CSS module class ID's stay constant?

Tags: css-selectors, cypress, css-modules, react-css-modules

CSS modules add ID's to the classes e.g. `classUc8xi`.

Since we want to target some elements with Cypress which uses some sort of QuerySelector, I want to know if these ID's ever change? Are they constant and identical for every user?

Is it a good idea to add these ID's to our Cypress tests like below or are there better options?

`selectBtn: '[class="select-buttonUc8xi"]'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of the `Uc8xi` is to scope the CSS to that particular component, i.e to stop CSS from one component from "bleeding" to another similar component.

The suffix chars is likely to be generated somewhat randomly, so no don't use that class as a selector.

Either add non-module CSS (it won't have a suffix), or explicitly add a `data-test` attribute to use instead.

Note that some React components won't pass the `data-test` on to the HTML page, you might have to add it to the topmost "concrete" element that renders on the component.

For example:

```js
function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1 data-test="my-hello">Hello, {props.name}</h1>;      // data-test id here
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
const element = <Welcome name="Sara" data-test="my-hello" />;    // not here
root.render(element);
```

**Test**

```js
cy.get('[data-test="my-hello"]')
  .should('have.text', 'Hello, Sara')
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand why the ID is there, but so far it seems to be consistent across our team for a while, so I was wondering if it would ever change. But its always better to use a dedicated attribute. We don't want to break Cypress when changing a classname. So we went with this.

Also curious why it needs to be in both the component and the actual element? I would assume that putting it in the h1 would always render it?

Comment: Yes, I agree putting it in the `<h1>` (in this example) is best. The other placement was meant to illustrate what *not* to do - probably not presented the best way.